# Keeping reference to member function from other another class

Tags: c++

I have an instance of a class A which should register a member callback in another instance of class B. I'm trying to keep the reference to the function of class A inside class B but I get a Segfault.

classA.h:

```
std::shared_ptr<classB> mB;
void toBeRegisteredCallback(const uint8_t val);
```

classA.cpp:

```
classA::classA(std::shared_ptr<classB> b) : 
mB(std::move(b)) {
  b->registerCallback(std::bind(&classB::toBeRegisteredCallback, this,
                                                      std::placeholders::_1));
}

void classB::toBeRegisteredCallback(const uint8_t val) {
  LOG(INFO) << "Received a value callback!";
}
```

Here is the code for classB.h:

```
public:
    void registerCallback(std::function<void(const uint8_t val)> callback);
private:
    std::function<void(const uint8_t)> _callback;
```

Here is code for classB.cpp:

```
void classB::registerCallback(std::function<void(const uint8_t val)> callback) {
        _callback = callback;
}
```

When I try to call the callback directly without assignment, it works fine:
`callback(8)`
However, if I try to assign it, I get a segfault at *functionswap*

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, preferably in a single source file that we can copy-paste and try ourselves.

Comment: Your `classA` ctor appears to `std::move` from the passed shared pointer `b`and then invoke a member function against that pointer with `b->registerCallback`.  Looks wrong.

Comment: Why would you want to move a shared pointer? Does your code work if you remove `std::move`?

Comment: Thank you all!
@G.M. Your comment helped out! I spotted the mistake! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your `classA` constructor...

```
classA::classA(std::shared_ptr<classB> b)
  : mB(std::move(b))
{
  b->registerCallback(std::bind(&classB::toBeRegisteredCallback, this,
                                                      std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

The initialization of `mB` will invoke (from [here(item 10))](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)...

```
shared_ptr( shared_ptr&& r ) noexcept;
```

> Move-constructs a shared_ptr from r. After the construction, *this
> contains a copy of the previous state of r, **r is empty and its
> stored pointer is null**.

Hence, in the following statement...

```
b->registerCallback(std::bind(&classB::toBeRegisteredCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

`b` is effectively a null pointer resulting in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to do, but I created a working example below.
You may give me feedback if that helps you, or if you need more explanation.
(As already mentioned by john you should be careful with the std::move command)

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class classB
{
public:
    classB() {}
    ~classB() {}

public:
    void registerCallback(std::function<void(const uint8_t val)> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }
    void callCallback()
    {
        if(_callback)
            _callback(8);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(const uint8_t)> _callback;
};

class classA
{
public:
    classA(std::shared_ptr<classB> b)
        : mB(b)
    {
      b->registerCallback(std::bind(&classA::toBeRegisteredCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    ~classA(){}

    void toBeRegisteredCallback(const uint8_t /*val*/)
    {
        std::cout << "Received a value callback!" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<classB> mB;    
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<classB> b = std::make_shared<classB>();
    classA localClassA = classA(b);
    b->callCallback();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The actual problem was that I was calling the registerFunction on a moved pointer, so this caused a null pointer deference. I should have used mB instead of b